# save outlook attachments with different names using power automate

Tags: power-automate

I have a template I have been using with great success in power automate flows.

[image]

my apply to each segment is as follows

[image]

this saves the file like...

[image]

my issue is I do not want the '_2023-03-09-0103' to show up in the sharepoint loaded attachment.  I have tried multiple online references using split, and trigger and cannot figure out how to make the name of the SharePoint file 'OrigamiUserList.xlsx'.  I know it lives in the ShrePoint - CreateFile - FileName field, I just cannot figure out the correct syntax to make it work.  When I replace the provided 'Attachments Name' option with 'OrigamiUserList' the program uploads a blank page with the name but not in excel format and with no data.  Thank you in advance

Comment: So how does the date get there?  It's in the original right?

Comment: That is correct.  It is coming from an automoated process that incorporates the date time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

A split function should do it for you.  I'm running a little blind here and can't reproduce your exact requirement but this shows how it can be done ...

**Flow**

[image: Flow]

The expression in the second step is ...

```
concat(split(variables('File Name'), '_')[0], '.xlsx')
```

Obviously, that could be improved given I am implying the extension but if it's always `.xlsx` then it will always work.

**Result**

[image: Result]